# How to solve non-symmetric, generalized saddle-point problem

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

From a discretization of an incompressible Navier-Stokes equation I get the following matrix

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}A & B_1^\intercal \\ B_2 & C\end{pmatrix}$$

Because my density is independent of the pressure, $C = 0$. But  $B_1^\intercal$ and $B_2$ are not transposed matrices, i. e., $B_1 \ne B_2$ and $A$ is non-symmetric, because we use upwinding for several physical properties like density or viscosity.

There are plenty of papers how to solve the symmetric saddle point problem. There are several on how to solve this for a non-symmetric $A$, like *Bramble, Pasciak, Vassilev, 1999* and its improvements.

I could not find a source which allows $B_1 \ne B_2$. For engineering problems with a non-constant density this should be a common problem. What's the best way to solve this kind of system?

Comment: What you want to solve? Saddle-point of what? Could you please explain a bit more.

Comment: Did you have a look [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/bgl05.pdf)? The "best" way would be to solve the problem by a direct solver, if your matrix is not too large.

Comment: @Fabian: Saddle point problem is a common term, so I don't get your question.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Great paper so far, and the first one which explains the case B!=C^t. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you are interested in inf-sup conditions, it could be interesting to look at Remark 4.2.7 in the book Mixed Finite Element Methods and Applications, by Brezzi, Boffi and Fortin.